# DbContext.Set<T>().Attach(entity)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Вопрос заключается в следующем.
Обновит ли метод Attach мою сущность?
Иными словами: обновится ли запись в таблице после аттача и сохранения изменений у контекста?

Comment: если у вас есть сомнения советую попробовать это в живую

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы вызываете DbSet.Attach вы говорите EF что "такая сущность уже есть в БД, записывать ее в базу не надо." Если потом вызвать SaveChanges то ничего не случится, сущность будет считаться не измененой (в статусе Unchanged). Об этом прямо в спрвке сказано.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.attach(v=vs.113).aspx